# Jsp Copy Data From Excel Files and Paste into the Input Box

Tags: jsp

I'm doing a program Where i need to copy data from excel and paste into Browser My Program is working well  When i paste data from excel into a text Box it's split all the rows in the table But I Want To Split Only the Cells That Contains in the First Column i don't Want to split all the rows ...

***Enter No Of Rows:

```
<form id='mform' action="EnterData" method='post'>
<table>
<tr> 
<td>
<button type="submit" value="Save">Save</button>
</td> 
<p style="color: red;">${message2}</p>
</tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>TIMEBlockNo.</th>
                            <th>TimeInformation</th>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
  <table id='myform'>

    </table>
    </form>








</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var i = 0;
function increment(){
i += 1;
}
function removeElement(parentDiv, childDiv)
{
if (childDiv == parentDiv)
  {
alert("The parent div cannot be removed.");
}
else if (document.getElementById(childDiv))
  {
    var child = document.getElementById(childDiv);
    var parent = document.getElementById(parentDiv);
    parent.removeChild(child);
    }
    else
             {
    alert("Child div has already been removed or does not exist.");
    return false;
    }
    }
function createRow()
{

    var j = document.getElementById("numm").value;
    var r = document.getElementById("myform");
    var mf = document.getElementById("mform");
    r.remove();
    var r = document.createElement("TABLE");
    r.setAttribute("ID", "myform");
    mf.appendChild(r);
    var n=0;
    for(var k=0;k<j;k++)
        {
    var rr = document.createElement("TR");
    r.appendChild(rr);
    for(var i=0;i<2;i++)
        {
       var d = document.createElement("TD");
        rr.appendChild(d);
    var a = document.createElement("INPUT");
    a.setAttribute("type", "text");
    a.setAttribute("onkeyup", "formatCells(this.value,'t1')");
    a.setAttribute("Name", "t1_" + n);
    d.appendChild(a);
    n++;
    }
    }

}
function formatCells(xls,group){
    var m =0;
    var arr Group = null;
    var arrGro = xls.split(" ");
    for(var l=0;l<arrGro.length;l++)
        {
     arrGroup = arrGro[l].split("\t");  
     for(var i=0;i<arrGroup.length;i++){
     document.forms[0].elements[group + "_" + m].value = arrGroup[i];

     m++;
     }
     }
     }


</script>
</html>***
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
<style>
input {
width: 80px;
}
table
{
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;
}
th,td{
text-align: left;
padding: 8px;
}
tr:nth-child(even)
{
background-color: #f2f2f2
}
th{
background-color: #4CAF50;
color: white;
}
</style>
Enter No Of Rows:  <input name="ss" id = 'numm' type="number" onkeyup="createRow()"><br>
<form id='mform' action="EnterData" method='post'>
<table><tr> <td><button type="submit" value="Save">Save</button></td></tr>
<tr>
<th>TIMEBlockNo.</th>
<th>TimeInformation</th>
</tr>
</table>
<table id='myform'>                    
</table>
</form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

function createRow()
{

var j = document.getElementById("numm").value;
var r = document.getElementById("myform");
var mf = document.getElementById("mform");
r.remove();
var r = document.createElement("TABLE");
r.setAttribute("ID", "myform");
mf.appendChild(r);
var n=0;
for(var k=0;k<j;k++)
    {
var rr = document.createElement("TR");
r.appendChild(rr);
for(var i=1;i<3;i++)
    {
    var d = document.createElement("TD");
    rr.appendChild(d);
var a = document.createElement("INPUT");
a.setAttribute("type", "text");
a.setAttribute("onkeyup", "formatCells"+i+"(this.value,'t"+i+"')");
a.setAttribute("Name", "t"+i+"_" + n );
d.appendChild(a);
n++;
}
}

}
function formatCells1(xls,group){
var m =0;
var arrGroup = null;
var arrGro = xls.split(" ");
for(var l=0;l<arrGro.length;l++)
    {
 arrGroup = arrGro[l].split("\t");
 for(var i=0;i<arrGroup.length;i++){
 document.forms[0].elements[group + "_" + m].value = arrGroup[i];
 m=m+2;
 }
}
}



function formatCells2(xls,group){
var m =1;
var arrGroup = null;
var arrGro = xls.split(" ");
for(var l=0;l<arrGro.length;l++)
    {
 arrGroup = arrGro[l].split("\t");
 for(var i=0;i<arrGroup.length;i++){
 document.forms[0].elements[group + "_" + m].value = arrGroup[i];
 m=m+2;
 }
}
}


</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thnx Nath it's working now I can implement this into my project

Comment: Is it possible to make for input box for column whenever user put the no of rows it's goes to the particular column